# Calling script/delayed_job start but nothing happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

On my server, I execute the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

But nothing happens (my job queue doesn't get emptied, no error is outputted, `locked_by` and `locked_at` remain NULL). `delayed_log.log` in my `/log` directory has write access, but nothing get logged to it. I'm only getting this warning:

> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125 in PATH, mode 040777

When I do `rake jobs:work`, however, it works and my job queue gets emptied.

Any reason why the former wouldn't work and the latter yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had 3 different versions of `delayed_jobs` installed.

`gem uninstall` + `bundle install` got it fixed.